# Calling a method from another class - SpriteKit/Objective C

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm programming a little SpriteKit game and I need some help regarding my enemy classes. 
I separated the enemy's "AI" from the gamescene itself and I'm calling it's methods from inside the game scene, just like that:

GameScene.m:

```
-(void)enemiesLevel1{
    EnemyClass* wave1 = [[EnemyClass alloc] init];
    [wave1 enemiesLevel1];
}
```

Enemyclass.m :

```
-(void)enemiesLevel1
{
    EnemyName = @"enemy1";
    SKSpriteNode* enemy = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:EnemyName];
    pathSpeed = 5;
    CGPathRef path = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(CGRectMake(0,0,10,10), NULL);
    SKAction *followTrack = [SKAction followPath:path
                                        asOffset:NO
                                    orientToPath:YES
                                        duration:pathSpeed];
    SKAction *forever = [SKAction repeatActionForever:followTrack];

    [self addChild:enemy];
    [enemy runAction:forever];
}
```

However, the enemy wont spawn. It's not adding the enemy child I think. I also tested out if the method is called by using NSLog and it actually showed up in the console, so what am I doing wrong?

**Edit**: EnemyClass.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>
#import "GameScene.h"

@interface EnemyClass: SKNode
-(void)enemiesLevel1:(GameScene *)scene; //Expected a type (Pointing to "GameScene *")
@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is you are not adding the enemies to the scene. You are adding it to an instance of Enemyclass. The following should correct this issue:

```
-(void)enemiesLevel1{
    EnemyClass* wave1 = [[EnemyClass alloc] init];
    // Pass the scene to your enemy class method
    [wave1 enemiesLevel1:self];
}
```

Your Enemyclass.m should look like this:

```
-(void)enemiesLevel1:(SKScene *)scene
{
    EnemyName = @"enemy1";
    SKSpriteNode* enemy = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:EnemyName];
    pathSpeed = 5;
    CGPathRef path = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(CGRectMake(0,0,10,10), NULL);
    SKAction *followTrack = [SKAction followPath:path
                                        asOffset:NO
                                    orientToPath:YES
                                        duration:pathSpeed];
    SKAction *forever = [SKAction repeatActionForever:followTrack];

    // Add enemy to scene not self
    [scene addChild:enemy];
    [enemy runAction:forever];
}
```

**NEW EDITS:** Change GameScene to SKScene in Enemyclass.h

```
-(void)enemiesLevel1:(SKScene *)scene;
```

and Enemyclass.m

```
-(void)enemiesLevel1:(SKScene *)scene
```

You no longer need this in Enemyclass.h, so delete it

```
#import "GameScene.h"
```

Comment: I tried out your solution but it just gives me an error in GameScene.m:

`[wave1 enemiesLevel1:self];  No visible @interface for 'EnemyClass' declares the selector 'enemiesLevel1:'`

Comment: Ahh right, how could I've miss that. However, it's still not compiling because it's "expecting a type" in the Enemyclass.h 

`-(void)enemiesLevel1:(GameScene *)scene;`

Comment: Did you add #import "GameScene.h" to the Enemyclass.h (not to Enemyclass.m)?

Comment: Yes, I did. I edited the Enemyclass.h code into my post.

Comment: Thank you so much 0x141E, you helped me out quite a bit!